# this keyword knockout binding in dojo application

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dojo

I am developing an application that uses knockout and dojo toolkit. I created a module but can not use **this** keyword inmethod as viewModel

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare", 
     "dojo/_base/lang",
     "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js"],  function(declare, lang, ko){
    var GeekService = declare(null, {
        geeks: ko.observableArray(),            
        constructor: function(){
            //this.removeGeek = lang.hitch(this, this.removeGeek);
        },

        removeGeek: function(item){             
            console.log(this)
        }.bind(this) // Ensure that "this" is always this view model
    });

    ko.applyBindings(new GeekService());
})
```

If I do not use `lang.hitch(this, this.removeGeek);` in constructor, I can not access ViewModel object via **this** keyword in removeGeek method.

Knockout samples, shows us that we can use **bind(this)** ensures "this" is always ViewModel. [here example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/simpleList.html)

the appplication above runs and console writes: Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}

But it should return GeekService wiewModel object.

Comment: I don't know how you might fix this using dojo but the reason this is happening is when you call `.bind(this)` the `this` is in the context of `function(declare, lang, ko){` which is global and hence `this` is `window`. `var GeekService = declare(null, {` is setting GeekService using an object literal instead of a function therefore `this` inside it does not get a new context of `GeekService`. In the example you linked `this` is the viewmodel because `SimpleListModel` is a function not an object literal: `var SimpleListModel = function(items) {`

Comment: I want to separate view and javscript object side, so I used this mix. The existing project is being developed with dojo toolkit.

Comment: Good overview on binding context: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html